# Getting the whole dirent structure in perl

Tags: linux, perl

The `readdir` syscall on linux returns a `dirent` structure that contains more information that just the file name, but it seems perl's `readdir` only returns the name (I've tried assigning it to a variable and using `Data::Dumper::dumper` on that to see if it was just something that stringifies to the filename - I don't know if that is a useable way to do that, but it was the best I could think of). Is there any way to get the other information (specifically I need the `d_type`), without `stat`'ing the name?

Comment: Dirent is unix only (BSD, to be precise). Perl is platform-independent. Could have something to do with that.

Comment: That is probably the reason why perls readdir behaves the way it does, but I had guessed that before asking the question, but that doesn't mean there couldn't be a way to get at the information (it could be cached, just like the results of stat are, and there could be a function that I didn't know of that return them).

Comment: What puzzles me is why you aren't just using Perl's `readdir` followed by `stat`, like the rest of the world. Using `IO::Dirent` will result in non-portable code that most people familiar with Perl won't understand. If you imagine you are writing faster code then this is certainly premature optimisation, and I very much doubt if reading a directory is a bottleneck for your program.

Comment: The code is not meant to be portable, and `stat`is comparatively expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IO::Dirent](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Dirent):

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use IO::Dirent qw(:ALL); # import constants DT_REG, DT_LNK, etc.

my %types = (
    DT_REG() => 'regular file',
    DT_LNK() => 'symbolic link',
    DT_DIR() => 'directory'
);

my $dir = 'foo';
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Failed to opendir '$dir': $!";

while (my $entry = nextdirent($dh)) {
    say join "\t", $entry->{name}, $types{ $entry->{type} };
}
```

Output:

```
..      directory
baz     symbolic link
.       directory
bar     regular file
```